# Getting Clients OS/Browser Details

Tags: client-side

Ok so I say a a site awhile back and I can't remember it for the life of me. It seemed fairly new but it was a site that you're client could go to, they'd enter your email and submit and it would send all their CPU details including which OS they have which browser and version they're running, etc. If anyone has any ideas what this site might be or any site that could do this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

---

It's more something that my client can go to and he'll submit the form on the page and it'll send me his details. Sorry it's not CPU info just browser and OS info.

Comment: Does this *need* to be an externally hosted web-app, or would you prefer to host such a thing yourself?

Comment: I guess either way but there's something already out there that's really nice. I just can't find it anymore. But if there is something you're thinking of I wouldn't mind takin a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser sends most if this information in every request. Look at: 
http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

For more hardware details a plugin can be installed in your browser. Futuremark does that for their benchmarks:
http://www.futuremark.com/benchmarks/onlinebenchmarks/

Answer (score 6):

I found what I was looking for: http://www.supportdetails.com/

Your client enters his email and your email and it'll send their details so you can see what you're working with.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be referring to something like http://www.findmebyip.com/

It certainly does not grab your CPU data (Javascript can't do that, as far as I know) but it sounds like what you described.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about an online service to achieve this, but it sounds very similar to the [CPU-Z application](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) (for Windows only, so far as I know). Although I don't believe that it'll email details automatically, but you don't say whether that's a requirement, so I'd hope that it's for analysis of your personal system, not someone else's.